# Single calendar with start and End Data Jquery DateRangePicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-daterangepicker

Well i'm working with some date stuffs and using jquery dateRangePicker. i want a config like follow which container single calendar with multiple(start and end) dates. is there any options or you could suggest me new one. Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDrGl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by making directive of that.

- Steps for your logic.

  - Make a directive
  - Add your stylings.
  - Add two fields for startTime and endTime.
  - Write logic accordingly for your startTime and endTime.
  - Generate a directive close event and return an object which contains date 
    with startTime and endTime.

You can find making directive guide [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).